# Create polymer templatizer without registering custom element?

Tags: polymer-1.0

I can create a custom component having Polymer.Templatizer behavior, and use that component to stamp out templates:

```
<dom-module id="my-template">
  ...
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-template',
      behaviors: [Polymer.Templatizer],
      ...
    })
    ...
```

```
...
var htmlTemplate = this.querySelector('template');
var myTemplate = document.createElement('my-template');
myTemplate.templatize(htmlTemplate);
var stamped = myTemplate.stamp({prop1:val1});
var target = ...;
target.appendChild(stamped.root);
```

Is it possible to create a stampable component without needing that custom element?

Comment: Have you tried using the `Polymer.Templatizer.templatize`/`Polymer.Templatizer.stamp` functions directly?

Comment: I tried, but cold not find a way to create an object on which to invoke them successfully (btw. it was your blog that brought me as far as to the solution with the custom element)

Comment: My question comes from the need to pass a template to a component. Meantime I got a simple solution: If I pass a <template is="dom-template"> then I can simply stamp that one out

Comment: Probably that is the best solution. I would post that as an answer. Maybe without accepting so that a better answer could come